# Can I use INotifyPropertyChanged in WCF?

Tags: wpf, wcf

In my WPF app, I call a WCF service to retrieve my business object.  I take that business object and bind it to a grid.  I want to now apply the INotifyPropertyChanged attribute, but am unsure if it would work from WCF.  My ultimate goal is to be able to edit items in a grid, click update and push those back through a WCF service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is an option for the generated classes to implement that automatically.

> **`svcutil /enableDataBinding`**
>   - Implement the System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
>   interface on all Data Contract types
>   to enable data binding.
>                                        (Short Form: /edb)

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about a partial trusted WPF app you can in .NET 3.5... You cannot in .NET 3.0..

If it is full trust you are talking about, I see no problems :)